# Use node.js to cache cookies?

Tags: node.js

Hey guys I am just starting off with node.js and trying to make a bot to send stuff for me on a certain site that saves the login data with a cookie, and after a successful I HTTP Post to the same site but a different directory and I am logged out, so I was wonder if there is any way to cache?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [whole article](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/sessions-and-cookies-in-node/) about it.

And [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies) is a [module for that](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies).

It is not that simple, you have to use external module for that (link above):

```
var http    = require( "http" )
var Cookies = require( "cookies" )

server = http.createServer( function( req, res ) {
  var cookies = new Cookies( req, res, keys )
    , unsigned, signed, tampered

  if ( req.url == "/set" ) {
    cookies
      // set a regular cookie 
      .set( "unsigned", "foo", { httpOnly: false } )

      // set a signed cookie 
      .set( "signed", "bar", { signed: true } )

      // mimic a signed cookie, but with a bogus signature 
      .set( "tampered", "baz" )
      .set( "tampered.sig", "bogus" )

    res.writeHead( 302, { "Location": "/" } )
    return res.end( "Now let's check." )
  }

  unsigned = cookies.get( "unsigned" )
  signed = cookies.get( "signed", { signed: true } )
  tampered = cookies.get( "tampered", { signed: true } )

  assert.equal( unsigned, "foo" )
  assert.equal( signed, "bar" )
  assert.notEqual( tampered, "baz" )
  assert.equal( tampered, undefined )

  res.writeHead( 200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" } )
  res.end(
    "unsigned expected: foo\n\n" +
    "unsigned actual: " + unsigned + "\n\n" +
    "signed expected: bar\n\n" +
    "signed actual: " + signed + "\n\n" +
    "tampered expected: undefined\n\n"+
    "tampered: " + tampered + "\n\n"
  )
})
```